# Create symlink to the package

Tags: linux, debian

I have installed Debian 9 and old LaserJet printer. When I run `hplip` installer it says:

```
error: A required dependency 'pyqt4-dbus (PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4)' is still missing.
error: A required dependency 'pyqt4 (PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x))' is still missing.
error: Installation cannot continue without these dependencies.
error: Please manually install this dependency and re-run this installer.
```

There are no such pakages in Debian 9 `pyqt4-dbus` and `pyqt4`.

They are called `python-qt4-dbus` and `python-qt4`.

The easiest way to solve this is to create symlink.

Answer (score 2):

You can also download the latest tar.gz file hplip-3.20.6 (https://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/).

And then run the installer without qt4 support:
`python3 ./install.py --no-qt4`

Answer (score 1):

There is a program [equivs](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/equivs) that can create fake/meta packages usually with just a dependency/conflict/etc. information. Its description says

> Another use is to circumvent dependency checking: by letting dpkg think a particular package name and version is installed when it isn't, you can work around bugs in other packages' dependencies. (Please do still file such bugs, though.)

It seems quite inelegant solution to me, but if everything other fails, maybe fake package can help.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to install pip, which is a tool for manage python packages.

```
apt-get update && apt-get install pip
```

Then you can easily run

```
pip install pyqt4 pyqt4-dbus
```

This should be work.